# Problem with Implementing a ListView in a Fragment (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, listview, kotlin, fragment

I am fairly new into programing with Android Studio and Kotlin. Until now I only worked with Activities to make my ListViews. I usually gather data from Google Firebase Database and then I parse it into a ListView.

I just learned about Fragments and Drawer Menus. I wanted to Implement a ListView on a Fragment, which displays data from Firebase. For that I reused the code I had from the other ListViews I previously did in Activities. The problem is, I need a application Context for my Adapter Class. I used the "*activity!!.applicationContext*" to get the Context and my Adapter Class shows no Errors.

The problem is, when I try to assign my created Adapter to my listView, I get this Error: "*Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> ErrorAdapter but ListAdapter! was expected*". I researched everywhere but I couldnt find any answer to this problem.

If you have any idea why this error occures, I would really appreciate your help :)

Thank you very much!

This is my Fragment ("listView.adapter = *adapter*" the italic font part "*adapter*" is red underlined in AndroidStudio):

```kotlin
class ErrorsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_errors, container, false)

        val listView = root.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.errorsList)

        val applicationContext = activity!!.applicationContext

        //Firebase Reference
        val myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Database")
        val errorList = mutableListOf<ErrorsInterface>()

        // Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.

                errorList.clear()

                for (data in dataSnapshot.children){
                    val errorData = data.getValue(ErrorsInterface::class.java)
                    errorList.add(errorData!!)
                }

                val adapter = {
                    ErrorAdapter(
                        errorList,
                        applicationContext,
                        R.layout.error_listview
                        )
                }

                listView.adapter = adapter

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed to read Values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

        return root
    }
}
```

This is the Adapter Class:

```kotlin
class ErrorAdapter(val errorList : List<ErrorsInterface>, val mCtx: Context, val layoutResId:Int): ArrayAdapter<ErrorsInterface>(mCtx, layoutResId, errorList) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        //Diese Variabeln sind für die Beschreibung des Bildschirmes verantwortlich
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResId, null)
        val error = errorList[position]
        val testtext = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.hallo)

        testtext.text = error.assignedPerson

        return view
    }
}
```

This is the Interface for the data:

```kotlin
class ErrorsInterface(val assignedPerson:String, val device:String, val jobDescription:String, val location:String, val resolved:Boolean, val timestamp:String, val type:String, val unixTimestamp:Long) {

    constructor():this("Nobody", "", "", "", false, "", "", 0)

}
```

Comment: Use `RecyclerView`

Comment: Remove the braces around the `ErrorAdapter` instantiation. Also, you don't want to use the application `Context` for that, or most things `View` -related. You want to use the `Activity` instead, as it will have the appropriate theme set on it.